# Copy file from url to my own server remains file to 0mb

Tags: php, copy, filesize, fread

I'm facing to a problem and I'm not really sure if this is the right way of doing this. I need to copy a file from a remote server to my server with php.
I use the following script :

```
public function download($file_source, $file_target) {
    $rh = fopen($file_source, 'rb');
    $wh = fopen($file_target, 'w+b');
    if (!$rh || !$wh) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($rh)) {
        if (fwrite($wh, fread($rh, 4096)) === FALSE) {
            return false;
        }
        echo ' ';
        flush();
    }

    fclose($rh);
    fclose($wh);

    return true;
}
```

but in the end, the file size remains at 0.

EDIT : I update my question, because there are still some things I didn't understand :
About fread, I used 2048mb. But it didn't work.
I found the script above, which uses 4096mb.

My question : How to determine which quantity of memory (?) to use in order no get the file downloaded anytime ? Because this one works on a specific machine (dedicated), but will it on a shared host, if I cannot modify the php.ini ?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filesize()` expects a filename/path. You're passing in a filehandle, which means filesize will FAIL and return a boolean false.

You then use that false as the size argument for your fread, which gets translated to an integer 0. So essentially you're sitting there telling php to read a file, 0 bytes at a time.

You cannot reliably get the size of a remote file anyways,  so just have fread some fixed number of bytes, e.g. 2048, at a time.

```
while(!feof($handle)) {
   $contents = fread($handle, 2048);
   fwrite($f, $contents);
}
```

and if that file isn't too big and/or your PHP can handle it:

```
file_put_contents('local.mp4', file_get_contents('http://whatever/foo.mp4'));
```

Comment: Ok, you were right. But just to know, because it's a bit confusing to me : what does 2048 refer to precisely ? Because in php doc it's said to be the length to read, and that it stops reading when it reaches the end of the file or when the length is reached.

Comment: exactly that. you don't know how big the file you're getting is, nor do you really need to. you just have to tell PHP how much it should actually get, which is 2048. if you're doing this repeatedly, then you should tune the number to something that fits your particular network packet size.

Comment: Hello, actually it's not working. I have to refresh or launch the script again to make it work.